# Android eclipse - Exclamation mark next to project name

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I changed the dependent projects of one of my project and moved one of my files there as an experiment.
I now moved it back but the project won't run.
It tells me I have an error even though I can't see one and "Clean project" doesn't help.
However, the project has an exclamation mark next to it. What does that mean?

Comment: Goto(Menu) -> *`Windows` -> `Show View` ->`Problems`* 
Then Select the error message and right click on it,then select `Quick Fix`.

Then come new window and find the error from it and resolve it.
Probably that error occurs when using third party library missing or path not found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check Errors window.
My first idea would be that no build target is set. Right click the Project, select Android and make sure that a Build Target is checked. Sometimes you need to uncheck it, select a different API, apply settings, and then again select the API that was originally selected.

Comment: Grr. I feel stupid. When I deleted the shared project I forgot to remove the dependency. :(