# Android - Exclamatory Mark Near Project Name

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently updated by Android SDK and now if i create a new project, i see a Exclamatory mark near my project name.

I Tried the solution in below links.

[Android:Error an Exclamation mark in my project how to resolve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193534/androiderror-an-exclamation-mark-in-my-project-how-to-resolve-it)

[Android eclipse - Exclamation mark next to project name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895860/android-eclipse-exclamation-mark-next-to-project-name)

After adding the correct library, i see R.java not getting generated. Tried cleaning and building the project multiple times. But still the same issue.

Need help on fixing this issue.

My Target SDK Version - 19 and min SDK Version is 8

Eclipse Version - 4.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
After adding the correct library, i see R.java not getting generated.
```

This implies that there is some error in your XML files.

Check the following in the order.

1. Name of all XML files should not contain capital letters.
2. In Values folder, in styles.xml file, try removing `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

After doing this, clean the project and build it. Check the Console window to see what error it throws. Make the corresponding change. It should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks. It was an issue with Styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an issue with an XML file providing the libraries aren't throwing any errors. You can check the "problems" tab in Eclipse to see where the errors are coming from. Most likely, it's with an XML file and once you fix that error R.java should compile and your project will be fixed.

[image]